# Ssh cisco server with paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cisco

I have cisco server (c220) and i want to start to build scripts to automate tasks.

I just need to know how to start ssh session with paramiko and write linux commands with this library(in phycharm 2.7 if its matter)

I will be happy if you can write for me an example to ssh cisco c220 server with ip x.x.x.x and to ask for him the health status.

Thank you very much!
Avi

Comment: in Pycharm I use fabric module.Fabric uses paramiko library. My suggestion would be to check fabric documentation. With fabric you can: copy files to remote, copy files from remote, execute linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, paramiko

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print "args missing"
    sys.exit(1)

hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
command = sys.argv[3]

username = "admin"
port = 22

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)

    client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read(),

finally:
    client.close()
```